# Does "Gangnam Style" contain any non-Korean words?

Tags: lyrics, pop, language, k-pop, korean

I used to assume "Style" was English and couldn't be Korean, but I subsequently found out that there's a Korean word based on the English word "style". However, I'm still wondering about what sounds like "Korea" and "Hey, sexy lady".

Does the song "Gangnam Style" contain any non-Korean words? (If I have to define "Korean words", I'd define it as appearing in either a non-specialised Korean dictionary for Koreans, or appearing in a non-specialised Korean dictionary for foreign speakers)

Comment: Welcome to the site and if you aren't doing so already, please support your local http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language !

Comment: @topomorto I'm currently committed to it http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/20755/andrew-grimm?tab=stats . I hope you manage to get into beta!

Comment: Cool :) yep I hope so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I used to assume "Style" was English and couldn't be Korean, but I
>   subsequently found out that there's a Korean word based on the English
>   word "style".

It's true that Korean has adopted the word 'style' into everyday speech, so a Korean might not feel they're "speaking English" when they use it, but even though it is a Korean word, you could still call it an English word too - it's spoken basically the same and means the same thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword goes into this concept. But by your definition, it would be in a Korean dictionary.

Anyway, back to the song..

- **Coffee** is also mentioned twice - the Korean version '커피' has been transliterated back as 'Keopi' in http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/psy/gangnamstyle.html. Like 'style', this is another loanword, so maybe not 'non-Korean' by your definition.

In that page you can also spot

- **"Eh, sexy lady"** (I always heard it more as *Hey*, sexy lady)
- **"Baby, baby"**
- **"You know what I'm saying"**

which are all English.

I don't think 'Korea' is mentioned - your ear may be catching 'geu wie' in the line *Ttwineun nom **geu wie** naneun nom*, which means something like 'the running man has the flying man above him'. (I think this is a saying that means "there's always room for improvement", "always room at the top... " - something like that.)